# Blog Posting SQL Join issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a blog at the moment in CI (CodeIgniter Framework). I have two tables:

- Blog_Post table
- Blog_Banners table

The relationships is one Blog_Post has many Blog_Banners.

I'm trying to retrieve all of the blog banners for a particular blog post using this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'blog_posts'
INNER JOIN 'blog_banners' 
ON 'blog_posts.id' = 'blog_banners.blog_post_id'
WHERE 'blog_posts.id' = '3'
```

I keep getting this message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''posts' INNER JOIN 'banners' ON 'posts.id' = 'banners.post_id' WHERE 'posts.id'' at line 2

Would anyone happen to see the error? I've been stuck for quite a bit on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use quotes for table/column names, use backticks. Also, integer shouldn't be quoted:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `blog_posts`
INNER JOIN `blog_banners`
ON `blog_posts`.`id` = `blog_banners`.`blog_post_id`
WHERE `blog_posts`.`id` = 3
```

But since there are no reserved words, you can do fine without backticks too

Comment: @Asaph Could you explain the edit you've made? That sentence was correct

Comment: Sorry about the lost sentence. That was an accident. I just brought it back.

Answer (score -1):

$this->db->query-("SELECT * 
FROM 'blog_posts'
INNER JOIN 'blog_banners' 
ON 'blog_posts.id' = 'blog_banners.blog_post_id'
WHERE 'blog_posts.id' = '3'");